# Tell system events to keystroke in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, editor, applescript

I'm making an application, in which I need to run a code that will tell system events to keystroke a certain phrase. Like in an AppleScript, I would do:

Tell Application "System Events" to keystroke "This is a test"

I don't know how to do this from Xcode, and I would really appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can run an AppleScript from code, e.g., using `OSACompileExecute`.  Also see QA1026.

Alternately, you can post keyboard events using the CGEvent APIs.  With recent OSes, you may be able to avoid posting each letter individually using `CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString`.