# Sending keystroke events to OSX

Tags: macos, events, send, keystroke

I wish to send keystrokes, including shift,ctrl,cmd,opt combinations, to OSX.  Basically anything that I can do on the keyboard.

How do I accomplish this?

I would also like to send mouse clicks. Is this a separate enquiry?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030070/tell-system-events-to-keystroke-in-xcode <-- I have found a duplicate, only the title is not very well worded.

Comment: Easiest way would be to use Applescript. Do you need an example >

Comment: Yes please.  Could you put it as a separate answer, if it is a viable alternative to the answer already given?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulating key press events in Mac OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379867/simulating-key-press-events-in-mac-osx)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `CGEvent` APIs, such as `CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent` followed by `CGEventPost`.

Answer (score 4):

Using applescript you can send any key you want. Here is an example of using various methods of sending keys :

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "h"
    keystroke (ASCII character 63)
    key code 38 -- Applescript's reference to keys
    keystroke "k" using {command down, control down}
end tell
```

With GUI scripting you can also send mouse clicks. These tend to be a little more involved. The following is an applescript I wrote to disable an option in System Preferences related to the Trackpad and three finger double tap.

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    set current pane to pane "Trackpad"
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "System Preferences"
            if window 1's tab group 1's checkbox 3's value is 1 then
                tell window 1's tab group 1's checkbox 3 to click
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
    quit
end tell
```